# Need Help in Some Custom Modification to single.php in a WordPress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using Custom Field Plugin Pro. I created 3 Fields and 4 Sub Fields of that. Now when I am trying to add the code in single.php WordPress theme editor, then it breaking posts page CSS.

**After figuring things I found that:** when I post the PHP code of just 1 field code then the website doesn't break. But putting 2/3 breaking the website. Also, I found when I put 1-1 entry in each fields then the website works fine with all 3 fields code. I don't know why this is happening.

This is the code I am using in single.php

```
<!-- Show Custom Fiels---------------->
<div id="Custom_Fields" class="sbox fixidtab">
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid white;
border-collapse: collapse;
background:black;
}
th, td {
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<?php
// Field 1 -----
if( have_rows('Field1') ):?>
<div class="custom_fields" style="overflow-x:auto;">
<h2><?php _d('Type : Name'); ?></h2>

<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type 1</th>
            <th>Type 2</th>
            <th>Type 3</th>
            <th>Type 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ( have_rows('F1') ) : the_row();
        $name_F1 = get_sub_field('name');
        $type_F1 = get_sub_field('type');
        $link_F1 = get_sub_field('link');
        $link_F1_full = "<a href=".$link_F1." target='_blank'>Visit Now</a>";
        $language_F1 = get_sub_field('language');
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name_F1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $type_F1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $link_F1_full; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $language_F1; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
    //endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
</div>
<?php
// Field 2 -----
if( have_rows('Field 2') ):?>
<div class="custom_fields" style="overflow-x:auto;">
<h2><?php _d('Type : Name'); ?></h2>

<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type 1</th>
            <th>Type 2</th>
            <th>Type 3</th>
            <th>Type 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ( have_rows('F2') ) : the_row();
        $name_F2 = get_sub_field('name');
        $type_F2 = get_sub_field('type');
        $link_F2 = get_sub_field('link');
        $link_F2_full = "<a href=".$link_F2." target='_blank'>Visit Now</a>";
        $language_F2 = get_sub_field('language');
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name_F2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $type_F2; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $link_F2_full; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $language_F2; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
    //endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
</div>
<?php
// Field 3 -----
if( have_rows('Field 3') ):?>
<div class="custom_fields" style="overflow-x:auto;">
<h2><?php _d('Type : Name'); ?></h2>

<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type 1</th>
            <th>Type 2</th>
            <th>Type 3</th>
            <th>Type 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ( have_rows('F3') ) : the_row();
        $name_F3 = get_sub_field('name');
        $type_F3 = get_sub_field('type');
        $link_F3 = get_sub_field('link');
        $link_F3_full = "<a href=".$link_F3." target='_blank'>Visit Now</a>";
        $language_F3 = get_sub_field('language');
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name_F3; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $type_F3; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $link_F3_full; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $language_F3; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
    //endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
</div>
</div>
```

If I put just code for field 1 then website is absolutely fine:

```
<!-- Show Custom Fiels---------------->
<div id="Custom_Fields" class="sbox fixidtab">
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid white;
border-collapse: collapse;
background:black;
}
th, td {
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<?php
// Field 1 -----
if( have_rows('Field1') ):?>
<div class="custom_fields" style="overflow-x:auto;">
<h2><?php _d('Type : Name'); ?></h2>

<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type 1</th>
            <th>Type 2</th>
            <th>Type 3</th>
            <th>Type 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ( have_rows('F1') ) : the_row();
        $name_F1 = get_sub_field('name');
        $type_F1 = get_sub_field('type');
        $link_F1 = get_sub_field('link');
        $link_F1_full = "<a href=".$link_F1." target='_blank'>Visit Now</a>";
        $language_F1 = get_sub_field('language');
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name_F1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $type_F1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $link_F1_full; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $language_F1; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
    //endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the names of your fields. I think your names are wrong. Then your `div` opens within your `if statement` but closes after your `if statement` and `destroys your html structure` if the statement is false. By the way, here you can read about the usage of repeater fields: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Look at this example:

```
<?php
// Field 1 -----
if( have_rows('F1') ): // i think it has to be F1 instead of Field1 here? 
?>
<div class="custom_fields" style="overflow-x:auto;">
<h2><?php _d('Type : Name'); ?></h2>

<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type 1</th>
            <th>Type 2</th>
            <th>Type 3</th>
            <th>Type 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php while ( have_rows('F1') ) : the_row();
        $name_F1 = get_sub_field('name');
        $type_F1 = get_sub_field('type');
        $link_F1 = get_sub_field('link');
        $link_F1_full = "<a href=".$link_F1." target='_blank'>Visit Now</a>";
        $language_F1 = get_sub_field('language');
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name_F1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $type_F1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $link_F1_full; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $language_F1; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><!-- RIGHT HERE -->
<?php
    //endwhile;
else:

    // no rows found
endif;

?>
<!--</div> WRONG HERE -->
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver Man. Thanks a lot. I didn't notice this way.